# tile size below 128 pixel won't render anything with CPU

Tags: rendering, tilesize

I set blender tile size to 16 and 32 and 64 and in the render window only alpha image (light and dark checker) shows even after rendering some tiles still nothing shows

But when set to 128 the tile will show up and render

I'm on CPU with cycles blender 3.6.2 I need to be on 16x16 tile

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was zooming so much on render image I couldn't see rendered tiles